# Find all Nash equilibrium given a game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following:

[image: description]

How can we find all Nash equilibrium of the game given that the attacker cannot perform surveillance.
I think for a mixed strategy there is but for a pure there isn't, but what the difference between these two strategies and how we find all Nash equilibriun for each strategy according to the picture.